# Unexpected vs. Unexpectable

Tags: meaning, differences

I came across an exercise in my schoolbook in which only **unexpected** was an accepted answer. I did some research, and found out that **unexpectable** is not a word you can find in dictionaries such as Oxford and Cambridge. However, [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unexpectable) offers a definition for it and this is a dictionary I trust. My question is... is the latter accepted only in spoken language? If not, what is the difference between the two words?

Comment: The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=expectable%2C+unexpectable%2C+expected%2C+unexpected&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cexpectable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunexpectable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cexpected%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunexpected%3B%2Cc0) gives no return for 'expectable/unexpectable' against 'expected/unexpected'.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done.

Comment: I have (as hyperlinks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unexpected is certainly the word you'd see the most (of the two).

[According to CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unexpected), **unexpected**, means:

> not expected

[According to MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unexpectable), **unexpectable** means:

> unpredictable

Those two are not the same, the first means: not in the line of expectation, it is not what we would expect. Unpredictable means something is hard or impossible to predict. Some example sentences (to clarify their meaning):

> That was unexpected, I never thought I'd win the lottery.
>
> Yesterday was totally unexpectable, the magician predicted the lottery numbers just hours before the draw!

As for if unexpectable is correct and addressing the word not being in most dictionaries, it has a prefix, "un", once we leave that out, we get **expectable**, which has an entry in [ELD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/expectable), but no definition (merely a redirect to *expect*). The question whether *expectable* is a proper word is also addressed [on quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-expectable-a-word), where multiple users agree and argue it is a word.